# Spatial and temporal information processing together (CNN and LSTM)

Tags: deep-learning, keras, cnn, lstm

I have small problem that requires to process both spatial and temporal information.

I need to predict vehicle's trajectory based on previous trajectory information and map information. My current situation:

1. Predicting future trajectory of vehicle was successfully done using seq2seq model. Where I give previous N points and model returns K possible trajectories
2. I have tried crop map information(based on vehicle's position) and giving it to CNNLSTM model with trajectory information. But even test accuracy was not good.

> What architecture is best for my problem?

P.S I am new to this forum. Feel free to improve question or point out my mistakes.

Comment: What are your input and output shapes?

Comment: @SaTa My model is not complete. Question is about model design. I have sequence of coordinates and map image. Output is sequence of coordinates.

Comment: I know. The architecture depends though on what the inputs are and what output you are trying to predict. What do you mean by a map image? Do you have an image per each time step?

Comment: I have N sequences of vehicle coordinate and map image for each record. I want to predict next N coordinates of vehicle